# TeraData on AWS: *** Warning: RDBMS CRASHED OR SESSIONS RESET. RECOVERY IN PROGRESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, teradata

I'm getting this error while trying to login to a Teradata instance running on AWS:

```
ec2-user@ip-xx-x-xx-xx:~> bteq

Teradata BTEQ 15.10.01.09 for LINUX. PID: 7460
Copyright 1984-2016, Teradata Corporation. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
Enter your logon or BTEQ command:
.logon 127.0.0.1/dbc;

.logon 127.0.0.1/dbc
Password:

*** Warning: RDBMS CRASHED OR SESSIONS RESET.  RECOVERY IN PROGRESS.
*** Warning: Exiting because of three BREAKs!

*** Exiting BTEQ...
```

I've tried to manually restart the instance by running `~/etc/init.d/tpa start` but got the error:

```
ec2-user@ip-xx-x-xx-xx:~> /etc/init.d/tpa start
Teradata Database Initiator service is starting...
Teradata Database Initiator service failed with 4 exit code
```

Comment: `pdestate -a` shows the current status. Check `/var/log/messages/`details what actually failed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
When I run the command `pdestate -a`, I get the error message:
`you are not authorized to run this command`
Also, there's no `var` folder on the TD database instance running on AWS

Comment: You need to do `sudo -i` so you log in a root account and then you'll be able to run `pdestate` and also see `/var/log/messages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I eventually resolved this problem was to create a new key-pair on AWS, which I then used to re-build Teradata on EC2. Why the former key-pair kept on throwing the error in the question is unknown to me.

Hope this helps someone else.